# Approximating a countable-state (infinite) Markov model with a finite-state one

Tags: poisson-distribution, markov-process, transition-matrix, discrete-distributions

## TL;DR—in a nutshell

I have a countable-state Markov model (with a countably infinite number of states) in which the probability of transitioning to states $S_{i>k}$ for large $k$s are practically zero, thus negligible.

Given this, I want to approximate the infinite-dimensional transition matrix with a finite transition matrix of size $k$, retaining only the first $k$ rows and columns. However, although the off-diagonal elements are close to zero for the states beyond $k$, the diagonal elements have non-zero values.

**The question is:** How can I make the smaller, approximate, transition matrix without messing with row-wise/column-wise properties of the stochastic transition matrix?

## Background and context (You may skip)

I am working with Jacob and Lewis's (1978) discrete autoregressive model (DAR), which can accommodate an AR(1)-like conditional expectation for any arbitrary marginal distribution as long as it is discrete.

In short, if you have an iid sequence $Z_t \sim \Pi$ (where $\Pi$ is a discrete distribution such that $P(z=i)=\pi_i$), and an independent binary iid sequence $V_t \sim binom(1, \tau)$ (wherein $0 \leq \tau \leq 1$), the sequence

$$
X_t = V_t X_{t-1} + (1-V_t)Z_t =
\begin{cases}
Z_t, & \mbox{if } V_t = 0
\\
X_{t-1}, & \mbox{if } V_t = 1
\end{cases}
$$

is a $DAR(1)$ process with the same marginal distribution as $Z_t$ (i.e., $X_t \sim \Pi$), with the conditional expectation of

$$
E[X_t|X_{t-1}] = \tau  X_{t-1},
$$

and an AR(1)-type given by $\rho(l) = \tau^l$ for nonnegative lags $l$.

The $DAR(1)$ model is a Markov process with transition probabilities given by

$$
p_{i|j} = P(X_t=i | X_{t-1} = j)=
\begin{cases}
(1-\tau)\pi_i, & \mbox{for } j \neq i
\\
\tau + (1-\tau)\pi_i, & \mbox{for } j = i
\end{cases}.
$$

***Note that** I write transition matrices as left-stochastic matrices, such that **columns** add to one.*

## Situation at hand

Since $DAR(1)$ can take any parametric or nonparametric discrete marginal distribution, I am trying to use a Poisson distribution for $\Pi$ such that $\pi_i = \frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}$.

In this case, by setting $\upsilon = 1 - \tau$ for readability, the elements of the (left-)stochastic transition matrix (for states $S_i \in {0, 1, 2, \ldots}$) are

$$
t_{ij} = p_{i|j} =
\begin{cases}
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}, & \mbox{for } j \neq i
\\
\tau + \upsilon\frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}, & \mbox{for } j = i
\end{cases};
\ \ \ 
i,j = 0, 1, 2, \ldots
$$

Thus the transition matrix (with elements starting from 0) would look like

$$
T_1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
\tau + \upsilon\frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} &
\ldots &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} &
\ldots  \\
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!} &
\tau + \upsilon\frac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!} &
\ldots &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!} &
\ldots  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} &
\ldots &
\tau + \upsilon\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} &
\ldots  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since $\frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!} \xrightarrow{i>k} 0$ quite quickly for large-enough $k$, the off-diagonal elements of $T_1$ become practically zero (for my application, $0 < \lambda < 10$ and $k \approx 20$). Thus, I want to reduce $T_1$ to a $k \times k$ matrix $T_2$

## Problem and questions, specifically:

From what I have said, it seems reasonable to make the following approximation:
$$
T_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
\tau + \upsilon\frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} &
\ldots &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} &
0 & 0 & \ldots  \\
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!} &
\tau + \upsilon\frac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!} &
\ldots &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!} &
0 & 0 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} &
\ldots &
\tau + \upsilon\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} &
0 & 0 & \ldots  \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{bmatrix}
\approx
T_1
$$

Then, to derive a finite-state Markov model, I want to formulate $T_3 for large enough $k$$ such that for a large enough $k$ I can "show"/"argue" that

$$
T_3 =
\begin{bmatrix}
\tau + \upsilon\frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} &
\ldots &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} \\
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!} &
\tau + \upsilon\frac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!} &
\ldots &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} &
\upsilon\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} &
\ldots &
\tau + \upsilon\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}
\end{bmatrix}
\equiv
T_2
$$

I have difficulty regarding the first approximation $T_2 \approx T_1$ it for a couple of reasons:

1. Although the off-diagonal elements of $T_1$ are almost zero for improbable states ($i,j>k$), the diagonal elements are non-zero (they have an additional $\tau$ in them). So, the approximation isn't simply replacing all improbable elements with zeros.
2. By replacing the improbable elements with zero, $T_2$ is no longer a (left-)stochastic matrix: The columns would not add to one.
3. There would be a similar problem for the marginal distribution of $T_2$ is messed up and cannot be derived from the Bayes rule applied to rows of $T_2$.
   More specifically, $\hat \pi_i = \sum_j (p_{i|j}\cdot \pi_i) \neq \pi_i$.
4. Following 3, the "marginal probability" (estimated using the Bayes rule in 3) doesn't add to one: $\sum_i \hat\pi_i \neq 1$.

And there is another problem in deriving the final conclusion that the finite-state Markov model described by $T_3$ being an approximation of the countable-state Markov model described by $T_1$:

5. How can one, algebraically, think of "equivalence" $T_3 \equiv T_2$ between matrices of different sizes?

**One solution to prevent the whole mess** would have been using another marginal distribution with (upper-)bounded support.
(Maybe an upper-truncated "Poisson" distribution, if exists?)
**However, I cannot do that** because it has implications that I must avoid for substantive/practical reasons.

I really appreciate your thoughts and help. Thanks in advance!

## Reference I cited

Jacobs, P. A., & Lewis, P. A. W. (1978). **Discrete Time Series Generated by Mixtures. I: Correlational and Runs Properties**. *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society*. Series B (Methodological), 40(1), 94–105. https://sci-hub.se/https://www.jstor.org/stable/2984870